# Add a word before the last occurrence of double quote

Tags: shell, sed

I'm using sed for auto-setup programs with shell scripts. I'm trying to add a word before last quote, the rules are:

- Must have double quotes in first argument because of variables
- The word before last quote is unknown
- I prefer a solution with sed command

The file:

```
values="word anotherword anyword foo"
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
wordtoadd="bar";
sed -i "s/^values=\(*.\)\"/\1$wordtoadd\"/" filetomodify.txt;
```

The desired result:

```
values="word anotherword anyword foo bar"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
sed '/^values=/s/\([^"]*\)"$/\1 '"$wordtoadd"'"/' input
```

Which, if finds a line starting with `values=`, replaces the longest match of a series of non-quote characters (`[^"]`) followed by a quote and the end-of-line (`"$`) with the match and `wordtoend`, also putting back the quote (`\1 '"$wordtoadd"'"`).

In your sed expression, `\(*.\)` should be `\(.*\)` to quantify the `.`. And you should also put back the `value=` part when substituting.

Comment: ty, i fix my sed command with your suggestions :), works well, can explain better your command syntax?, specially ( $ and [^"]*).

Comment: @Lyoneel, added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(.*)"/\1'"$wordtoadd"'"/' file
```